# AppModel aftersave, get controller function name

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

I'm trying to log every write operation so I'm using the afterSave and afterDelete callbacks in AppModel. Basically I need to log(for the moment): the model , the controller function, the loggedin user data and the remote ip
It seems that I was able to get all of them but I don't know how to get the controller function name.
This is the aftersave function I have now:

```
public function afterSave($created) {
    App::uses('Folder', 'Utility');
    $month = date("y-m");
    if(!is_dir('../tmp/logs/'.$month)) {
        $dir = new Folder('../tmp/logs/'.$month, true);
    }
    App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');
    $user_id = CakeSession::read('Auth.User.username');
    if($created) {
        $id =   'New';
    } else {
        $id =   $this->data[$this->alias]['id'];
    }
    $str = 'WRITE Action. Model: '.$this->alias.'. Controller: functon_name. ID:'.$id.'. Username: '.$user_id.'. Client IP: '.$this->getIP();
    CakeLog::write($month.'/'.date("d-m-y"), $str);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing this on the model, which has no knowledge of the controller (and really shouldn't). I'd suggest copying the `CakeRequest` object to the model so you have that information. Here's one way:

```
//controller
function beforeFilter() {
  $this->{$this->modelClass}->request = $this->request;
}
```

Then you can access the request object from the model. Use `$this->request['params']['action']` to get the current dispatched action.

It's worth suggesting that you might want to move this to the `read()` method on a custom datasource, as `afterSave()` can possibly be skipped and therefore not logged.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. I did as you said, I put the code in beforefilter, in the app controller. However The problem was that for some reason I had an empty output on $this->request['params']['action'], in the appmodel so I used $this->request->action which worked well. Can you explain better in which cases the afterSave could be skipped? Thank again, that was really useful.

Comment: `afterSave` can be skipped if you pass `'callbacks' => false` in the save options. Behaviors, etc. can modify this if they wanted to.